# How to clear texture on view

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I use Framework Cocos2D to make my little game.

I used 3 object:

CCTMXTiledMap at background at layer -1

CCRenderTexture to render some line with texture at layer 0

CCSpriteBatchNode to render game object at layer 1

I  use CCRenderTexture at z-oder 0. When i try to render some Texture on this, its working perfect, but when use Clear function to clear the Texture in viewport to redraw another texture, it's clear Map too.

> [target clear:0.0f g:0.0f b:0.0f a:1.0f];

How can i so this problem?

Thanks you ! –

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//For removing all textures
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeAllTextures];

//For removing un used textures
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeUnusedTextures];
```

Comment: Hi ShinuShajahan .Thanks for your answer my question but in my situation i want to clear texture and redraw new, your code just clear all texture cache. :)

Comment: [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeTexture:yourTexture];

Comment: Thanks ShinuShajahan but itsn't work with me.i guest because i use sprite and visit function to draw in texture.my code look like that
 [target begin];
 if (distance > 1)
 {
  int d = (int)distance;
  for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
  {

   [brush setPosition:ccp(start.x + (difx * delta), start.y + (dify * delta))];
   [brush setRotation:rand()%360];
   [brush setScale:r];
   [brush visit];
  }
 }
 [target end];
.Sorry i canot format the code

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, but my solution was to just use [target clear:0.0f g:0.0f b:0.0f a:0.0];.... see the difference there. The alpha is zero. We're clearing the screen with the colour black though we are putting the alpha to zero. That will DEFINATELY work if I think you are trying to sort out what I think you are.